# git branch change history count by day

Tags: git

I'm trying to recreate a history of when builds would have occurred caused by changes on a branch in git between two dates.

I can't seem to work out from git-log or git-rev-list exactly the options I need to specify to get that.

I'm looking only for commits that were directly on the branch, or merge commits from other branches. When I try I seem to get histories of work on those remote branches as well, but I don't want those, since those commits would not have caused the target branch to build, because they would have been on other branches.

I need to do this for our master and develop branches, but whenever I try I get numbers that are way too high for master, since that's only used to create releases, so I'd expect less than 100 in my case, but it's returning a few thousand.

Can anyone help?

I'm using Powershell.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to get the number of commits on a branch between two dates? Could you show us the commands you're trying, please? Rather than using dates, does your build system record the commit ID it's building? Also a `git log --graph --decorate --oneline` would help us (and you) to see the true history of your repository and perhaps why you're getting too high a count.

Comment: Basically I want a list of dates where a branch changed (as that is what triggers a build on our build server). So if develop changed 4 times in one day, I want that date listed 4 times. I have attempted using `--first-parent` (see response to @jnrbsn below).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you want the [`--first-parent`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---first-parent) option of [`git-log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). That will only follow the first parent of each merge commit encountered, which the *destination* of the merge.

For example, on your `master` branch, you could do...

```
git log --first-parent master
```

...and that would only show you commits directly on `master` (probably none of those, I'm guessing) and merge commits that were merged *into* `master`.

Comment: I don't understand why `git log --pretty=format:'%cd' --date=short --after="2017-04-01" --before="2017-09-14" --first-parent develop` yields the same result if I replace `develop` with `master`.